# How to use stock login controls in VS 2010 Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I was wondering, say if someone creates a new Web Application in Visual Studio 2010, it comes with a login page as well as with a page for a new user registration. Is there an online tutorial on how to use those for a "real life" example?

PS. Possibly a video tutorial, maybe YouTube?

**EDIT**: Here's a couple of screenshots of what I mean:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I did, that's why I'm asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control is the [ASP.NET Login Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There are a few video tutorials online, for example [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQ24S08jC9U) one.

**Update:** There is a walkthrough [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on creating an ASP.NET site with user login which might be more in line with what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not exactly what I am asking for. In that tutorial he created controls from scratch. In a new VS 2010 web app project there're pages already pre-made for logins, registration, etc.